# How to make the subview outside the bounds recognize the touches

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a subview. When a button in the subview is tapped, the subview expands outside the bounds of a view, presenting couple of other buttons. However, I cannot find a way to interact with them.

I found a code at Apple's site:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

// Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
// The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview
CGPoint pointForTargetView = [self.targetView convertPoint:point fromView:self];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.targetView.bounds, pointForTargetView)) {

    // The target view may have its view hierarchy,
    // so call its hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
    return [self.targetView hitTest:pointForTargetView withEvent:event];
}

return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

However, I cannot understand how should I use it, so that my subview will recognize the touches.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the `UIView` or which ever class you need and override that method. Then create an object of that subclass and use it. It will then recognize the touches.